# How to fake a Android hardware device?

Tags: android

I'm developing for Galaxy Note specifically. I want to test my app on a real device which I don't have. Is there some way I can fake a Galaxy Note on AVD?

I do know how to create an AVD with hardware matching Note. However, that won't suffice. I want the app to identify AVD as a real device. I have small hints in general direction:
1) Somehow install stock Note ROM on AVD.
2) Modify build.props and create my own ROM.

I also have a Galaxy S phone, if something can be done on that. Thanks.

Comment: In an AVD are every time serverial things you can identify that. E.g. the OS.Build contains a SDK or the IMEI is set to zero...

Comment: What is the difference between an AVD being identified as a real device.  What is the specific reason you want to do this (will be helpful to identify how to do what you want).

Comment: To be able to do a Build.Model call and get "Galaxy Note" returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this only on real Device, because this information is wrote only on the firmware of device. You can try to debug on remote real devices. Search on http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/bbs/lab/view.do?platformId=1
or here http://www.perfectomobile.com/portal/cms/services/android